# Time series regressions

Tags: regression, time-series, trend, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

I'm trying to make a basic scatter plot/regression to look at the relationship between two time series. Series a is volume of mentions of a product on a forum over time, series b is the sales of the product over time. The series are at the weekly level, with matching dates, across four years.

I'm interested to know if there is a relationship between greater mentions and sales (obviously there is no direct causal relationship, they are likely both being mediated by another variable; however, that investigation will come at a later date—for now I just want to see if there exists a relationship).

My first method was to difference the data to remove the trend and seasonality and then run a regression on the variables.

My second method was to decompose both series and then regress over the residuals/remainder of the decomposition.

My third was just only detrending the data (basic linear detrend).

What's making me think twice, is that the products in some cases *are* seasonal so maybe I shouldn't be deseasonalising them; however, at the same time I feel like I should be more interested in the relationship regardless of seasonality. I'm confident I should be detrending so as to get rid of any spurious correlations from just general growth in numbers; however, I'm in two minds about removing the seasonality. Obviously with it left in we see a stronger relationship than with removed.

Question one: is it appropriate to regress over the residuals of a decomposition (I can't seem to find a good steer on this; however, I don't see anything inherently wrong with this)?

Question two: should I be sometimes detrending and sometimes differencing depending in the results of the KPSS and ADF tests?

Question three: should i be deseasonalising? My gut said yes, now it says no.